# I am getting error while using sessions in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 tables `Users` and `Hobbies`. userId`is primary key in`Users`table and it is foreign key in`Hobbies`table. I want same`userId`in both tables. When user logged in he gets`userId`. On next page there is hobbies page where user have to fill info and the same`userId` should get saved into Hobbies table. I am using session for this, but it is giving exception as

`"Error converting datatype object to int."`

My code is:

this is a code on Users Page

```
protected void loginbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select UserId from Users where username=@username and password=@password",con);
    Session["ID"] = cmd1;
}
```

and this is the code on hobbies:

```
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id= Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId",id);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I am new to sessions and stored procedure. This is my first web app. Please help me to improve.

Comment: please see the edit and let me know if any issues!

Comment: I modified my code as u said. But it is giving me exception as:ExecuteScalar requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've tagged your question as C#, please correct it if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't store a `command` in a session let along convert it to a `integer`.

**loginbtn_Click**

```
protected void loginbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string conString = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(
        "select UserId from Users where username=@username and password=@password",
        con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password.Text);
            var id = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            Session["ID"] = id;

        }
    }
}
```

**Button4_Click**

```
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string conString ="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Users where UserId=@UserId",con))
        {
            var id= Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId",id);
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                //get the data
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the `SQLCommand` first to get the value of your `UserID`. Right now, you are passing an `SQLCommand` object, which obviously isn't an integer value. To fix the error, you would need to do something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection (connectionstring))
{
 SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select UserId from Users where username=@username and password=@password",con);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password.Text);
 con.Open();
 int UID = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar(); //Execute command and assign value
 Session["ID"] = UID; //Now set session variable
}
```

Of course, you need to handle exceptions and so on, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

First i want to notify you that you are storing the `command` object into the `Session` and not the `UserID`. so you are getting this error!

On `Users.aspx` Page:

**Storing UserID in session:**

```
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection (yourConnectionString))
    {
     SqlCommand mycmd = new SqlCommand("select UserId from Users where  username=@username and password=@password",con);
    //add parameters to pass the username & password here
      mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username.Text);
      mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password.Text);
     if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
      {
           con.Close();
           con.Open();
      }

     int userID = (int)mycmd.ExecuteScalar();
     Session["UserID"] = userID; //Store USerID in session
     con.Close();
    }
```

The reason I'm not simply using:

```
if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    con.Open();
}
```

Is because the `ConnectionState` can also be:

```
Broken, Connnecting, Executing, Fetching
```

Additionally Microsoft states that Closing, and then Re-opening the connection "will refresh the value of State." [More Details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.state%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

On `Hobbies.aspx` Page:

**Using Session UserID:**

```
if(Session["UserID"]!=null)
{
int userID=Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"])
//do other stuff
}
```

**Insert Into Hobbies table:**

```
private void btnInsertHobbies_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int userID=0;
        if(Session["UserID"]!=null)
        {
          userID=Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
        }

        //add Here fields of hobbies table
        string hobby1= textBox2.Text;
        string hobby2= textBox3.Text;
        if (conn2.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
           conn2.Close();
           conn2.Open();
        }

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn2;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Hobbies(userID, hobby1, hobby2)   VALUES(@userID,@hobby1,@hobby2)";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", userID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hobby1", hobby1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hobby2", hobby2);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

        conn2.Close();
    }
```

**NOTE:** please make changes according to your table fields and mark as answer if it help you!

Comment: Not quite right. He is getting user name from `TextBox` and querying database to get the user ID.

Comment: Procedure or function 'spInsertHobbie' expects parameter '@userId', which was not supplied.

Comment: you have not passed parameter that is required by stored procedure hence this error. Please see the edit!